# UIButton setSelected: NO doesnt show default background image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a custom `UIButton` with 2 background images:

```
in Default State: default.png

in Selected State: selected.png
```

set in the Xib File.

This is gets invoked on button touch down:

```
-(IBAction)numberSelected:(id)sender{
  NSLog(@"Button pressed %@",[sender currentTitle]);
  UIButton* button = (UIButton*)sender;
  button.selected = !button.selected;

  [button release];
}
```

The wrong behavior is this:

I press the button, the background image switches to `selected.png` (correct), I press it again, and no background image is shown. I press it another time, the app crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to release the button there. Remove

```
[button release];
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot to set : `UIControlStateSelected` adding the image.

```
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

### Edit:

Why do you make `[button release];` Of course it will crash the second time.

Comment: no, same behavior, the images for the states are set in the xib file.

Answer (score 1):

```
 [button release];
```

**This statement has to be removed!**